# Created Zoom app (oauth). It doesn't appear in my Windows client apps list

Tags: zoom-sdk, zappdev

I have created a Zoom app (oauth app type).  I can use the "local test" and everything seems correct.  I can't get the app to appear in my Zoom Windows client.  I want to test the user experience of actually clicking the app in the apps list.

I've checked all the admin permissions and "pending approval" lists, and that doesn't appear to be the cause.  When I launch the Windows client, then click the "Apps" icon along the top, I see other apps, but not the one I created.  When I click the "Manage" link in the apps list, I do see my created app under both the "Apps in Production" and "Apps in Development" list.  App Info: "User Managed/Unpublished"; Shared Access Permissions: "Authorized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done yet.  This can only be done by creating a "Zoom App" , which currently hasn't yet been released as a capability for general developers.  The Zoom Apps which currently exist were built by organizations that were part of a program that is not longer accepting new members.

The apps that can currently be built by the development tools on Zoom's site (just called "apps", apparently) do not run and can not be launched from inside of Zoom.